# How to convert marathi html page to pdf with kokila font in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts

I am using itextsharp for convert html page to pdf with marathi font (Kokila font), I want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application.

```
protected void btnCreatePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    string strHtml = string.Empty;
    string pdfFileName = Server.MapPath("~/files/div.pdf");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    strHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    CreatePDFFromHTMLFile("<div  style='font-family:arial unicode ms;'>" + strHtml + "</div>", pdfFileName);

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", "div.pdf"));
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.WriteFile(pdfFileName);
    Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter(myStringBuilder);
    HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter);
    idcovert.RenderControl(myWriter);
    string HTMLContent = myTextWriter.ToString();
}
```

I expect the output pdf in marathi font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default iText7 doesn't support Devanāgarī  script. You need to use the add-on: [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph), there are code examples on that link.

Comment: Is there have any Free Api?

Comment: They are giving Java Code but i need C# Code !

Comment: There's no free version of this, you'll need to pay. The C# code is in the documentation for the product, once you've paid for a license they'll provide guidance on writing the C# code.